# Regex multiple quotes mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I have html with multiple `width="1" height="1"`. I'd like to replace all of them with `border-image: none`.

I've tried:

```
$printCanvas.html().replace(new RegExp("width=\"1\" height=\"1\"", 'g'), "border-image: none");
```

and seems didn't work. Any suggestions?

-----update------

To those who asked why I don't need `style`tag:

Actually, I was trying to process the HTML which generated by googlemap in `Edge` and `IE10`. I am using a library, which convert that jQuery div into an image and it works in `Edge` but didn't in `IE10`. Namely, html2canvas. My output here: [issue with IE10, IE9](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/750)

After carefully comparing the html, I saw the only difference is below:

In `IE10`, it has `width="1" height="1"` tag:

```
   <div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img width="1" height="1" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; position: absolute; -ms-user-select: none;" draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google4.png">
```

in `Edge`:

```
<div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; position: absolute; -ms-user-select: none;" draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google4.png">
```

I am thinking just using regex to change all `width="1" height="1"` to `border-image:none`:

```
printCanvas.html().replace(new RegExp("width=\"1\"\\s+height=\"1\"", 'g'), "border-image: none");
```

and then ask html2canvas library to process it:

```
window.html2canvas(printCanvas, {
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");               
      base64Img = img;
      base64Img = base64Img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
      resolve(base64Img);
    }
  });
```

and nothing has changed....still show blank on IE10.

below is the screen compare of the rendered html in both browser:

[image]

Comment: have you tried escaping the space between width and height attributes?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: With your current example, you are getting the html of printCanvas and then replacing the css styling (width/height data attributes), but the value that is being returned by `replace` is not being assigned to the $printCanvas's html. Also your code will not have your desired effects. `border-image:none` needs to be inserted into an inline style block, not in your data attributes for an element.

Comment: try `$printCanvas.html().replace(new RegExp("width=\"1\"\\s+height=\"1\"", 'g'), "border-image: none");`

Comment: Shouldn't you replace it with `style="border-image: none"`?

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple issues.

1. The `html().replace()` returns the modified string, but you are not assigning it back to the print canvas's html. (i.e. `$printCanvas.html(resultString);`).
2. You cannot swap out the `border-image` css style with data attributes `width=1px`.

Recommended approach:

Find the elements that have a width of 1 and a height of 1 (data attributes).
JQuery one line approach (if you specify pixels):

```
$('*[width="1px"]*[height="1px"]').css('border-image', 'none');
```

If you do not specify pixels in your HTML (which I'm assuming based off your code):

```
$('*[width="1"]*[height="1"]').css('border-image', 'none');
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/madc9b25/.

Comment: thank you for this solution, after investigating my issue, I feel like the issue I have might be related to other problem rather than the regex... But this solutions just helped me to understand more.

Comment: Sean, he was trying to replace the width and height to 0 as well. Otherwise good.

Comment: check html and css are generated by Googlemap. check this fiddler, http://jsfiddle.net/tsPmt/9/  Run it in IE10 and Edge separately and inspect the Googlemap part `div id="map-canvas"`, you will see the two browsers are returning different HTML. I was trying to make all IE10 rendered code look similar to Edge to tackle my problem.

Comment: Try editing the HTML in the F12 Developer tools first and see if it works. If it does then Sean's solution is very close to what you wanted. Just needs to be modified a little bit.